# Creating an image of the installed version along with all changes and apps installed

Tags: system-installation, iso, system

Well my requirement is little different from other question related to image  creation. 
I need to do is-

**Scenario** : I've Ubunut Mate 18.04 installed with over dozen tweaks/changes to make it suitable to my needs and over it I've many programs installed (VS code, node etc.)

**Requirement**: I need to make an image (bootable) from this OS that has my changes and installed programs in it. Let's call it *MyOs.iso* (assuming w'll make an iso).

**Purpose**: If I try out other distros/flavors and install them in my system, I could any day install from my MyOs.iso and have my system ready considering I need to get back.

It would be icing on the cake, if we can find an option to make this iso 
a) with the data

b) without the data

This would further help me in using my iso as - restore point and for changing my laptop as well.

My purpose can be fulfilled by creating a restore point, if the other version I try can be installed on the entire system (without making a side by side installation) but keeping the restore point intact.

Comment: Seems identical to most questions about creating a bootable image of a customized system. Perhaps you could highlight the differences.

Answer (score -2):

Even I'm looking for the same.. there is a software in windows name norton gost, think it will work for Linux system too.. just browse for Norton Gost software and give it a try..